# Grails Error - TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, grails

According to [this tutorial](https://grails.org/wiki/quick%20start) I was configuring a simple grails application. It worked fine with the internal database that comes with grails. Then I was trying to connect an oracle database with the app but Im getting the following error.

> Error 2015-10-06 14:21:37,774 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application:
>   Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
>   extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the
>   following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of
>   SID given in connect descriptor  ) Message: Error creating bean with
>   name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while
>   extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the
>   following error: ORA-12505, **TNS:listener does not currently know of
>   SID given in connect descriptor**

This is my DataSource.groovy file

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username = "system"
    password = "password"


}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@tan.example.com:1521:orcl;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
            pooled = true
            properties {
               maxActive = -1
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
               numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
               testOnBorrow=true
               testWhileIdle=true
               testOnReturn=true
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already have the jdbc driver in the lib folder. Any idea what is wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the url be: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@tan.example.com:1521/orcl` ?

Comment: Tried it. Error says invalid format

Comment: First try to connect to the database with sqlplus using this command - sqlplus system/password@orcl. If that works you'll know your DB is working fine and is accessible, and then we can continue to solve the problem in grails.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my test server. TESTSERVER is of course the server name but could also be the IP address.

```
development {
    dataSource {
        pooled = true
        dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect
        driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
        username = 'username' // YOUR USERNAME AND PASS
        password = 'password'
        url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@TESTSERVER:1521:TESTDB'
        dbCreate = 'update'

    }
}
```